# mod_rewrite with two parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im getting a headache over this.

If the requested css file has qp defined it should rewrite as line 1. But if it doesn't it should rewrite as line 2.

Why isn't this working?

```
RewriteRule /css/(.*).css?qp=(.*)$ /build/css.php?request=$1&qp=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule /css/(.*).css$ /build/css.php?request=$1 [QSA]
```

Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

Comment: Assuming your htaccess is in root folder, you dont need the leading slash in your rule. `/css/` should be `css/`. Also, you can try to add the L flag in your rewrite options `[QSA,L]`. This translates into something like: you found the match, stop searching and execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove leading slash from RewriteRule. It doesn't receive it. And doesn't receive Query string. If`qp` is present, `QSA` will save it. Must be enough:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^css/(.*).css$ /build/css.php?request=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Line 2 worked before, when I only needed 1 variable. With leading slash

Comment: The first rule doesn't work at all because it is not correct. Because of the `[QSA]` flags, the second rule also does what you intended for the first rule. You can safely remove the first rule. In case you want to make it work (without the second rule being present) then read about [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). `RewriteRule` doesn't handle the query string. `RewriteCond` does.

Comment: @axiac You are right. That is why 1 line solushion is in the answer